# AWS Classic Load Balancer HTTP termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, tcp, amazon-elb

AWS [a](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html) say:

> When you use HTTP (layer 7) for both front-end and back-end
>   connections, your load balancer parses the headers in the request and
>   terminates the connection before sending the request to the back-end
>   instances.

What is that supposed to mean? I know I should use Keep-Alive, etc. but this  piece of writing is really confusing. If the connection is terminated(and by the way it's TCP, not HTTP level) then a server will have no way to respond to the request.

Answer (score 2):

*"**terminating** the connection"* in this context means that the load balancer is the connection endpoint, i.e. that there is one TCP connection between the client and the load balancer and another one between the load balancer and the server. Terminating the connection does not mean **closing** it at the TCP level. Instead the connection between client and load balancer is kept open and the payload is forwarded between this connection and the connection(s) between load balancer and server(s).